# Segurança de Certificado Auto-assinado ( Self-Signed Certificate)

Tags: java, segurança, criptografia, ssl, certificado-digital

Estou fazendo um sistema Cliente-Servidor em Java que irá gerenciar computadores em uma sala, o cenário é o seguinte:

- Um computador, o servidor, espera por conexões, quando é feita uma ação ( Bloquear Tela ) esse comando é então enviado a todos os clientes conectados.
- Os clientes, são os que são controlados, tem o IP do servidor, e eles se conectam ao servidor com esse IP, uma vez conectados, aguardam por comandos.

Pela natureza do programa, ele deve ser o mais seguro possível para que apenas pessoas autorizadas possam utilizá-lo.

Foi então utilizado o SSL para a comunicação.

- Usando o openssl criei um certificado auto-assinado, converti para pks12, keytool para fazer as duas keystores( ou melhor, a keystore para o servidor, e a truststore, com um certificado apenas, para os clientes).
- O servidor tem a keystore com o certificado e a chave privada, encriptado usando AES/CBC/PKCS5 e a chave de 256 bits derivada usando PBKDF2 com 1.000.000 de iterações (leva 2 segundos para decriptar). e a senha é segundo esse site: https://apps.cygnius.net/passtest/ ( 65 bits de entropia )
- Os clientes, a truststore com o certificado apenas.
- Ao ligar o servidor, deve ser informada a senha para abrir a keystore e ser capaz de aceitar conexões dos clientes.

Minha pergunta é: 
Se o cliente confia apenas em um certificado, que foi recebido na instalação, o problema da autenticação de certificado auto-assinado teoricamente estaria resolvido, sendo tão seguro quanto ao SSL comum, baseada na corrente de confiança dos CA's?
O fato de o certificado ser Auto Assinado estraga de alguma forma a criptografia, como permitindo se obter a chave privada a partir da pública auto-assinada, ou algo do tipo?

obs: a truststore do cliente tem apenas o certificado, e NÃO tem a chave privada.

obs²: assumindo que a chave privada seja mantida em segredo, ou seja, ninguém roube a keystore do servidor e descubra a senha da mesma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A verificação feita através do chain dos CAs é para garantir que aquele certificado é confiável ou seja a Autenticação do mesmo. Em um ambiente público, para garantir isso é necessário que uma entidade certificadora confiável assine seu certificado.
Nesse seu caso, como seu sistema só confia em um certificado, não tem problema ser auto-assinado. Você já conhece e confia nesse certificado.

O fato de ser auto-assinado não influi nada na criptografia, esta será garantida igualmente como num certificado assinado. Você ainda garantirá a **confidencialidade** dos dados, só não a **autenticação**, que nesse seu cenário não é necessário, visto que você já faz isso através do truststore.